# Limit tag word count

Tags: tags, count

I want to limit user to enter post_tag only words of two not more that. If any of the tag is more than two words the user caanot publish the post.

I need to use this function to count word.

```
function count_words( $text ) {
    $text2 = preg_replace( '/<.[^<>]*?>/', ' ', $text );
    $text2 = preg_replace( '/&nbsp;|&#160;/i', ' ', $text2 );
    $text2 = preg_replace( '/[0-9.(),;:!?%#$¿\'"_+=\\/-]*/', '', $text2 );
    $text2 = trim( $text2 );
    if ( $text2 == '' ) {
        $count = 0;
    } else {
        $count = preg_match_all( '/\S\s+/', $text2, $matches );
        if ( $count !== false ) {
            $count += 1;
        } else {
            $count = -1; // Error!
        }
    }
    return $count;
}
```

this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wypiekacz/ has several rules but not tag word count. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `pre_insert_term` filter:

```
function wpse_189722_limit_tag_words( $term, $taxonomy ) {
    if ( $taxonomy === 'post_tag' ) {
        if ( count( preg_split( '/\s+/', trim( $term ) ) ) > 2 )
            $term = new WP_Error( 'term_too_many_words', 'Maximum of 2 words' );
    }

    return $term;
}

add_filter( 'pre_insert_term', 'wpse_189722_limit_tag_words', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. How to show the error with admin_notice to post.php. the above solution do not print the error to post.php. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not straightforward. If you want to pursue a solution I would suggest asking a new question.

Comment: thanks for your nice solution I am just trying to print the error message when ever user add tags through post-new.php with https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189745/showing-wp-error-message-with-admin-notice-action-hook