# admin_notices not working in post editor

Tags: hooks, admin, notifications

I'm trying to fire an admin notice from within a `pre_insert_term` filter (have also tried it as an action). Example:

```php
add_filter( 'pre_insert_term', 'pre_insert_term_action', 10, 2 );

function pre_insert_term_action( $term, $taxonomy ) {
    add_action( 'admin_notices', 'show_example_error' );
    return $term;
}

function show_example_error() { ?>
    <div class="error">
        <p>My example warning message.</p>
    </div>
<?php }
```

So I add a tag in my post and hit the *Update* button, but it does not show me the admin notice as expected.  If I put `die()` calls within both functions, it is showing me that the functions are firing as expected, first `pre_insert_term_action()` above, then `show_example_error()`.

When I add my `admin_notices` action outside of the `pre_insert_term_action()` function scope, the admin notice does display.  So if the functions are firing in the expected order, why is my admin notice not displaying if the action is added in the first firing function?

There's an accepted answer in [this related question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189745/showing-wp-error-message-with-admin-notice-action-hook) suggesting to use `add_settings_error()` but that didn't do anything that I can visibly see.

I also find it weird that if I define a `$GLOBALS` variable in my `pre_insert_term_action()` function, it doesn't return a value when I call it in `show_example_error()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like there is some page redirecting going on in the post updating process, hence why I can't even access a `$GLOBALS` variable. The only alternative I found to use was to use a session variable.  Something like:

```
add_filter( 'pre_insert_term', 'pre_insert_term_action', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'show_example_error' );

function pre_insert_term_action( $term, $taxonomy ) {
    if ( MY CONDITION THAT WARRANTS A WARNING NOTICE IS TRUE ) {
        if ( session_id() === '' || ! isset($_SESSION) ) {
            session_start();
        }
        $_SESSION['show_my_error_message'] = true;
        return new WP_Error( 'code', 'message' );
    }
    return $term;
}

function show_example_error() {
    if ( session_id() === '' || ! isset($_SESSION) ) {
        session_start();
    }
    if ( isset($_SESSION['show_my_error_message']) ) {
        ?>
        <div class="error">
            <p>My example warning message.</p>
        </div>
        <?php
        unset($_SESSION['show_my_error_message']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for something like this:

```
function my_notices() {
      $screen = get_current_screen();
      if ($screen->id === 'your-id') { //or anything else
        if (isset($_GET['save'])) { // or $_SESSION or transient

          <div class="error">
            <p>My example warning message.</p>
          </div>

        <?php }
      }
}
add_action('admin_notices', 'my_notices');
```

Let's see the WP Screen object also. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Screen

### EDIT

You can use `$_GET`, `$_SESSION` or check for transients set during `save_post` actions or similar, like the `pre_insert_term` filter. [Good explanation here](https://www.sitepoint.com/displaying-errors-from-the-save_post-hook-in-wordpress/).

Comment: The admin notice is dependent upon what happens in the *pre_insert_term* filter, therefore I need that filter or action to run first to determine whether or not to fire an admin_notices action.

Comment: Yes but this is another approach and adding actions inside filters is not the right way. You should use the right `admin_notices` action and inside that process your term, getting the post object and eventually display the notice.

Comment: I can't run the necessary `pre_insert_term` filter or action from inside the `admin_notices` action because `pre_insert_term` has already ran.

Comment: But you can manipulate it. Please formulate your ultimate goal with that.

Comment: How? My goal is to avoid a user being able to add new/non-existing tags if they're not an administrator and the only way I know how to do that is within the `pre_insert_term` filter. Then I can't seem to communicate to the `admin-notices` hook the result of that.

Comment: Interesting edit note. How can the $_GET method be used to dynamically display messages checking for $_SESSION variables?

Comment: Yes, forgot to update it.

Comment: Your link was a valuable read! Thank you for the insight.

Comment: Glad it helped. Always welcome.